# Where is the best place to put Android SDK on Mac?

Tags: android, macos

On the Android development website I can see the instructions for installing the Android SDk:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools
It doesn't say where is the best place to put it and install it on a Mac system? I ask because I need it to be able to be accessed from either admin or a regular user, but also as a best practice.

Comment: Jut put it under `/home/[user]/[any_folder]`.

Comment: Thanks. You can put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
brew install android-sdk
```

Then update your PATHs like so

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$(ls $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools | sort | tail -1):$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/shark/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/shark/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

#Hierarchy Viewer Variable
export ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm sh monitor
```

Try sticking with `/Users/shark/Library/Android` or your default Users folder.